# How to write a custom WaitUntil that is reusable?

Tags: unity

In my turn based game, I like to have a function similar to Unity's [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html), [WaitUntil](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) that can be called within a IEnumerator that suspends the coroutine execution for the given amount of moves. I already have a public working UnityEvent (moveEvent) which I could listen to.

So I could call it from any IEnumerator like:

```
IEnumerator Example()
{
    yield return new WaitForMoves(2);
}
```

I think I'd need a separate class like:

```
class WaitForMoves {

  int moves = 0;

  void Start() {
    Game.moveEvent.AddListener(OnMoveComplete);
  }

  void OnMoveComplete() {
     moves++;
  }

  // I'm not sure how to write this in a way that it waits
  // until this.moves === movesToWait
  public WaitForMoves(int movesToWait) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html

```
class WaitForMoves : CustomYieldInstruction {

  private int movesLeft;

  public WaitForMoves(int moves) {
    movesLeft = moves;
    Game.moveEvent.AddListener(OnMoveComplete);
  }

  void OnMoveComplete() {
    movesLeft—-;
    if (movesLeft <= 0)
      Game.moveEvent.RemoveListener(OnMoveComplete);
  }

  public override bool keepWaiting {
    get {
      return movesLeft > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And to use it, just as you wanted:

```
yield return new WaitForMoves(2);
```

If you have a global move counter in Game, then you wouldn’t need to have a listener at all:

```
class WaitForMoves : CustomYieldInstruction {

  private int targetMoves;

  public WaitForMoves(int moves) {
    targetMoves = moves + Game.moveCounter;
  }

  public override bool keepWaiting {
    get {
      return Game.moveCounter < targetMoves;
    }
  }
}
```